# Run a command in container after deployment in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure for hosting and Azure Pipelines for CI/CD operations

I have an image build and deploy operations defined like that:

```
- stage: Package
  displayName: 'Package app'
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: 'Build image'
          inputs:
            containerRegistry: '$(containerRegistry)'
            repository: '$(containerRepository)'
            command: 'build'
            Dockerfile: './Dockerfile'
            buildContext: '.'
            tags: |
              $(Build.BuildId)

        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: 'Push image'
          inputs:
            command: push
            containerRegistry: '$(containerRegistry)'
            repository: '$(containerRepository)'
            tags: |
              $(Build.BuildId)

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(subscription)
          appName: $(appName)
```

What should I do to execute some operations in my container **after** task `AzureWebAppContainer` is finished? I have to make some database updates after the deploy operation.

I've tried to find documentation for Azure and search for some SO topics, but didn't find any solutions yet, except usage of entrypoint / cmd for database updates, which is not working for me
I think there should be some Azure pipelines mechanism to perform such actions

Comment: Hi Yaro, what's the latest status of your issue? Any progress?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT by some business-related causes I've resolved it with some workaround (and I'm not really happy that I did it this way).
Your suggestion should work, but not in my case. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [startup command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-web-app-container-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#:%7E:text=containerCommand%20%2D%20Startup%20command) in the `AzureWebAppContainer@1` or the [AzureAppServiceSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-app-service-settings-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to manage the afterward operation.

By the way, you could also refer to this doc for [Azure Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-docker-webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml) to get more details.